# Create Access GUI to interface with Database

Tags: sql, vba, user-interface, ms-access

I'm looking to create a basic GUI using MS Access which will allow me to add some DB values. I was wondering if this would be easier using Access itself, VBA or another function like Macros through Excel. Basically I need to do the following.

- Create UI to add new value to DB quickly (over manual input)
- Create UI to extract updated information (SQL style) then output as graph format/ existing budgeting format

A larger question to this would be is it worth it to use Access or is there an easier way to change the tables and extract the relevant information.

Comment: I'm not sure but I think you can change values directly in the table-view... With a Gui you can make it easier to understand for all users...

Comment: Need help with forms. I realized that I need help implementing forms so that I can edit and filter certain values in tables. Is that doable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of the options you've listed, I would choose an MS Access front end.

If multiple users (more than one) are going to be using this application, you're going to need an MS Access front end, and a back end (placed on a shared network/drive). You would then link the tables from the backend to the front end via [linked table manager](http://hitechcoach.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=60:how-to-manage-your-linked-tables&catid=65:split-database).

If you choose MS Access as a front end also, and you aren't familiar with SQL, it will be a little easier because of the QBE interface Access provides.

Access is not a *very* powerful tool this day in age, but it is great for RAD (Rapid Application Development) for quick, hasty projects that are fairly simple (such as what you're describing the need for).

Creating forms is very simple in Access, and you can provide a direct link between a form and a table for adding, updating and deleting records via [bound forms](http://www.dhdurso.org/articles/ms-access-forms.html). You can also easily show data by providing a query (using SQL like you referenced) as the RecordSource for a form. You can even write VBA code to export your results to excel if that is necessary.

If I didn't cover something that you're confused about, please let me know and I will update my answer.

Comment: If I create a form and need it to update the table, how would I do that so that it does not act as a filter? I created it to have the inputs needed but not I cannot find a method to add the new inputs to the table. Lastly, to create an updated report for (ie: create a report for last 9 months with x as starting date) would I need SQL or VBA code or is there a way to use Access' own functions to do that?

Comment: @VaibhavGupta "so that it does not act as a filter" - I don't know what you mean by that. For your report, see my post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25443879/creating-a-form-where-user-inputs-start-and-end-dates-of-a-report/25447941#25447941) (except you'll only want a start date field)

Comment: @VaibhavGupta Great - happy to help. Good luck on your project.