# Microsoft Access VBA Passing Parameters to a Report

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have form `frmScreen`, which has 3 fields `File_Number, id, country`. The data is fetched from `Screen` table as a data source.The `report` has the same data source

I have a button on the form which calls report rptScreen. I want to pass file name as parameter to the report so that the report displays only

```
Select * from Screen where File_Number=<parameter passed through the form?
```

I checked previous posts on StackOverflow but it doesn't help me out.

So how do I pass parameters and what changes should I do in the report so that it takes the `File_Number` field as parameter and shows only the records that match the query

My code looks like the following

```
stLinkCriteria = "[File Number]=" & "'" & Me![File Number] & "'"
   DoCmd.OpenReport "rptScreen", acViewPreview, , stLinkCriteria
```

**Error: The report shows all data instead of record only for that `file number`**

Comment: Why is there a space between `file` and `name`? And did you happen to see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25447941/2679750)? It may help.

Comment: @MarkC. That's how the field names are designed by someone else and unfortunately i cannot change the field name.

Comment: When you type `Me.` what does intellisense give you as options for the field names? I highly doubt it's `file name`

Comment: Sorry you are right, let me update the question

Comment: @MarkC. I have updated the question

Comment: How are you providing data to your report? Through the query in your question? Is it the record source for your report?

Comment: If you test this as a new query in the Access query designer, does it return the rows you would want displayed by your report? `SELECT * FROM [Screen] WHERE File_Number=Forms!frmScreen!File_Number`

Comment: @MarkC. For report data source is same Screen table

Comment: @HansUp yes in query designer when i run Select * from Screen where File_Number='12' it displays the records of that file number

Comment: Is `File Number` a text value? Or is it actually a Number data type? If it's a number, get rid of the leading / trailing `'` and see if it works then.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman When i use a msgbox stLinkCriteria  it displays the value now, the problem is the report is showing all records, so what changes should i do in the report.

Comment: You said this query worked in the query designer: `Select * from Screen where File_Number='12'`  That strongly suggests the name of the table field is `File_Number`, not `File Number` ... so your `stLinkCriteria` should use `"[File_Number]"` instead of `"[File Number]"` immediately following `stLinkCriteria = `

Comment: @HansUp Thanks that helps, what changes should i do in the report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your report's `Row Source` to return all rows ...

```sql
SELECT * FROM [Screen]
```

Then you can open the report with `DoCmd.OpenReport` and use its *WhereCondition* option to filter the report's data as you wish ...

```vb
stLinkCriteria = "[File_Number]='" & Me![File Number].Value & "'"
Debug.Print stLinkCriteria '<- check this in Immediate window; Ctrl+g will take you there
DoCmd.OpenReport "rptScreen", acViewPreview, , stLinkCriteria
```

Notes:

1. `Screen` is an [Access reserved word](http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueBadWord.html#S).  Although it may not be causing trouble here, I bracketed that name in the `SELECT` statement just to be safe.  But it would be better to give that table a different name if possible.
2. I presumed `Screen.File_Number` is a valid field and `Me![File Number]` refers to a control on the form.  But due to the earlier confusion surrounding space vs. underscore in those names, that presumption seems shaky.
3. If you open the report directly (like from the Navigation pane) instead of with `DoCmd.OpenReport` and a *WhereCondition*, it will include all rows from the table.  That may not be what you actually want, but for now let's try to get something basic working.